# How to add time dummies in a regression?

Tags: time-series

I would be grateful if someone teaches me how to use time dummies in a regression to capture the effect of introducing a law. I am doing a study on reforms by assessing the pre and post effect of a law which was introduced in 2006 but was operational in 2008 by firms.

Comment: This may be too broad to be answerable. You may want to see if you can narrow this down to a focused question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not very specific about your case, but here are some general guidelines. The essential part is that you create $T$ new time dummies, where $T$ is the total number of time periods. Then for each observation, one (1) of the time dummies are equal to 1, if that observation belongs to the that time period.

Assume you have two periods, 2005 and 2008. For all the observations in 2008, the dummy 2008 is equal to 1, and 0 otherwise. The same goes for 2005. You could mask the net even smaller, and define dummies for months, days or even hours or seconds.

I don’t know which outcome analysis you have in mind, but I will assume (linear) regression. Then you simple include the time dummies, expect one of them. This is to avoid inducing perfect linearity - the one dummy you leave out, is captured by the intercept. 
The other dummies can then be view as a difference in intercept. You could interact the time dummies, with other variables. For instance difference in education return, dependent on which year you have.